# QSystemNetworkInfo not found

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

I want to compile a Qt project on desktop, but I get an error:

> QSystemNetworkInfo: file not found.

I have added INCLUDEPATH to my .pro file, but I still get the error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSystemNetworkInfo` class is part of the [QtMobility APIs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-latest/index.html), which is unfortunately unavailable for desktop targets.